# Может ли одно и то же слово быть и союзом, и предлогом?

Tags: значение-слов, предлоги, союзы, части-речи

Может ли одно и то же слово использоваться и как союз, и как предлог?

Comment: Хорошо бы видеть это слово.

Comment: Спасибо SHAMPAR. я не могу вам показать это слово. Этот вопрос возник случайно. Оказалось, что в английском языке слово until/till может быть и союзом и предлогом. Стало интересно, а как в русском языке, может ли быть предлог союзом или наоборот? с тех пор я в поисках такого слова....

Comment: Спасибо вам, Александр, большое за ответ. В моей голове все встало на свои места! Важно, что теперь я знаю: союзы и предлоги - штуки разные. А то они у меня все на одно лицо были....;-)

Comment: Евгений, спасибо за вопрос. Успехов!

Comment: Я вот не уверен, что союзы с предлогами такие уж разные штуки. Например, в предложениях "Вася с Петей пошли в магазин" и "Вася и Петя пошли в магазин", на мой взгляд, разницы между предлогом и союзом ровно ноль. Но я подробно не исследовал этот вопрос, надо будет почитать про них.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Чистых" таких слов в русском языке вроде бы нет. Только в сочетании с местоимением, а в большинстве случаев ещё и с союзом, предлог может входить в состав сложного союза, например:

[**НЕСМОТРЯ НА**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_482)
[**НЕСМОТРЯ НА ТО(,) ЧТО,** *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_483)

[**ВСЛЕДСТВИЕ**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_119&layout=item)
[**Вследствие чего (этого),** *в зн. союза*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B5&all=x)

[**ИЗ-ЗА,** *предлог*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B7%D0%B0&all=x)
[**ИЗ-ЗА ТОГО, ЧТО,** *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_821)

[**БЛАГОДАРЯ**, *предлог*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_56)
[**БЛАГОДАРЯ ТОМУ, ЧТО,** *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_57)

[**ДЛЯ,** *предлог*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?bts=x&word=%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F)
[**ДЛЯ ТОГО(,) ЧТОБЫ,** *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_172)

[**ДО,** *предлог*](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?word=%D0%B4%D0%BE&all=x)
[**ДО ТОГО(,) КАК,** *союз*](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_176)

Comment: Да — и здесь всё распрекрасно!

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова Римма, за ответы на поднятые вопросы ++.

Comment: И тебе — премного... https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B5&oq=%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BC%D0%B8&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i512l9.6795j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#fpstate=ive&vld=cid:15df1a48,vid:PktdYYD8d9c

Comment: Почти сплю... Может, потом?.. Что-то похожее уже было. А утром — со зверюгой — по льду — в лес... Или на море...

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова  Ух, здорово! Хороших снов!